# Get content of selected tab item

Tags: c#, wpf, tabcontrol

I have a window and it contains a tab control. Every tab control contains a UserControl to display.

How can I get the active tab's content object and call a method of that object?

Comment: If it is a tab control in wpf than you can use TabControl.SelectedItem

Comment: Try something like `var ctrl = tabCtrl.SelectedContent as UserControl;`

Comment: But every tab has different control. How can I get it polymorphically?

Comment: @TalhaIrfan see my edited comment.

Comment: @TalhaIrfan I'm going to update your question so it matches the problem a little better. Meanwhile check my answer below...

Comment: So, is your question answered?

Comment: Only half - Now how to call it's method?

Comment: @helb Its not working either

Comment: @Rachel can you please have a look here and guide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the content of the currently selected tab item with `TabControl.SelectedContent`:

> Gets the content of the currently selected TabItem.

This will return whatever you placed in the tab item. You can get it safely as UserControl if you only place your own controls in the tab items.

```
var ctrl = tabCtrl.SelectedContent as UserControl;
```

Of course, instead of `UserControl` you can use any common base class of the actual control you are using.

**EDIT:** To call a method on a specific control, you can cast to the actual type:

```
if(ctrl is MySpecificControl1)
{
    var myCtrl1 = (MySpecificControl1)ctrl;
    myCtrl1.MySpecificMethod();
}
```

Comment: @TalhaIrfan What do you mean? Do you get an exception? Please be more specific.

Comment: When I write: TabItem ctrl = mainTab.SelectedContent as WorkSpaceViewControl;  It gives me error that I cannot implicitly convert TabItem to WorkSpaceView Control. Explicit conversion required?

Comment: this is because you try to implicitly covert the result to `TabItem`. Try with `var ctrl = ...` instead of `TabItem ctrl = ...`

Comment: Ah thats my mistake. But Problem is still arising in 2nd portion as I told earlier: var myCtrl1 = (WorkSpaceView)ctrl;  Cannot convert type TabItem to WorkSpaceView